# Create, Start and Stop Linux Systemd Service

Tags: linux, ssh, services, systemd

Via remote ssh access I am trying to create a systemd service, if service was not created previously, create a new one if not check if the service is active and then stop it, update the service and restart it. if the service is not active then update the service and start it. I tried the following.

```
     - sshpass -p "password" ssh -o stricthostkeychecking=no -t -t user@ip "mkdir -p FROM_REMOTE/ABS/inlaks-gt-cashout/ && cd FROM_REMOTE/ABS/inlaks-gt-cashout/ && [[ ! -f service.sh ]] && echo 'java -jar inlaks-gtb-cashout-service-1.1.jar' > service.sh || echo 'File already exists'"
     - sshpass -p "password" scp -o stricthostkeychecking=no target/inlaks-gtb-cashout-service-1.1.jar user@ip:FROM_REMOTE/ABS/inlaks-gt-cashout/
     - sshpass -p "password" scp -o stricthostkeychecking=no service/inlaks-gt-cashout.service user@ip:FROM_REMOTE/SERVICES/ 
     - sshpass -p "password" ssh -o stricthostkeychecking=no -t -t user@ip "cd /etc/systemd/system && [[ ! -f inlaks-gt-cashout.service ]] && sudo cp /home/asodad/FROM_REMOTE/SERVICES/inlaks-gt-cashout.service /etc/systemd/system/"
     - sshpass -p "password" ssh -o stricthostkeychecking=no -t -t user@ip "systemctl is-active --quiet inlaks-gt-cashout.service systemctl stop inlaks-gt-cashout.service"
     - sshpass -p "password" ssh -o stricthostkeychecking=no -t -t user@ip "cd /etc/systemd/system/ && sshpass -p 'password' sudo systemctl start inlaks-gt-cashout.service && sshpass -p 'password' sudo systemctl enable inlaks-gt-cashout.service && sshpass -p 'password' sudo systemctl daemon-reload"
```

I worked the first time but on subsequent trials, I keep getting

> Failed to start inlaks-gt-cashout.service: Unit inlaks-gt-cashout.service not found.

I have tried removing the service and reloading the systemctl and even reset the failed units using `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl reset-failed` but same result.

The blow is my `.service` file

```
        [Unit]
        Description=Start Inlaks gt cash out service
        After=network.target
        [Service]
        Type=simple 
        Restart=always 
        WorkingDirectory=/home/asodad/FROM_REMOTE/ABS/inlaks-gt-cashout  
        RestartSec=5
        StartLimitInterval=0 
        User=asodad 
        ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/asodad/FROM_REMOTE/ABS/inlaks-gt-cashout/service.sh 
        [Install] 
        WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Hi, some security issues... do not write your password plane (-P ...), it is possible to read it from local and remote machine even with other users. Second does your user have the right to run `systemctl is-active --quiet` without `sudo`? In the other lines you put...

Comment: without sudo it does not have the access to @Hastur